# How to Configure Wso2 AM and BAM?

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

I am using WSO2 API Manager (1.8) and WSO2 BAM server(2.5.0) . I have done the 
      following configurations for getting statistics.

Configurations in  : 
            https://github.com/Prasanthmv/Wso2/blob/master/configurations/all.doc

After that I started BAM and AM, but the following error appears :(I have
              pushed the error in github):

[AM error](https://github.com/Prasanthmv/Wso2/blob/master/am%20error/wso2carbon.log)

[BAM error](https://github.com/Prasanthmv/Wso2/blob/master/bam%20error/wso2carbon.log)

Why this error is showing, is my configuration 
              correct?

Answer (score 1):

Here's documentation on how to set up API Manager / BAM integration: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM180/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics

Alternatively, you can use [WSO2 API Cloud](http://wso2.com/cloud/api-cloud) (SaaS version of API Manager) in which everything is preconfigured and works out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

According to the carbon logs, You must be using windows 7.

Therefore,

This could be due the BAM cannot execute cygwin commands. Please try to install Cywin into C drive and make sure no space in file path and append "C:\cygwin64\bin" to the windows PATH (using "Edit the system environment variables").